# Can I provide nil for the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

> dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
>   Returns a reusable table-view cell
>   object located by its identifier.
>
> - (UITableViewCell *)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString
>     *)identifier
>
> Parameters identifier A string
>   identifying the cell object to be
>   reused. By default, a reusable
>   cell's identifier is its class name,
>   but you can change it to any arbitrary
>   value.

Ok so if by default it's the class name, why should I put much brain force into thinking about an identifier? Could I provide just nil? Would it then use the class name? Or what did they try to say here? Must I make an NSString with the class name by myself and provide it as identifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The identifier will be used as a key in an internal NSMutableDictionary of NSArray to store the reusable cells. If you provide `nil`, the `-objectForKey:` used in `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will crash.

Besides, a table may have cells from different (sub)classes of UITableViewCell, so there's no good default value to pass either.

Comment: so if I would make an NSString from class name, would that be a solution?

Comment: @mystify: Yes. But I tend to just give a dummy string e.g. `@"."` as an identifier.